# Uploading file with FormData and XmlHttpRequest with Formidable on node js backend shows empty files, fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, formidable

I am uploading a csv file using FormData and XmlHttpRequest. Here is the code for that.
I have a form wrapped around an html input type file, whose onchange event I am executing this code. I have tried to send the form directly as well and also read the form element into the FormData object.

```
      let formData = new FormData();
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      var blob = new Blob([file],{type: 'text/csv'});
      formData.append("payoutUpload", blob, 'processed.csv');

      let uri = encodeURI(`${window.serviceUri}${path}`);

      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.onload = (result) => {
        if (req.status === 500 && result && result.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
          console.log(
            'Connection was reset, hence retry the sendRequest function'
          );
        } else if (req.status === 200) {

        } else {
          console.log("Error while retrieving data");
        }
      }
      req.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log('There was an error while retrieving data from service', e);
      };
      req.open('POST', uri, true);
      req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      req.send(formData);
```

When I send the request, I can see that the file is being sent in the form of Request Payload.

On the NodeJs backend, I am running Express and Formidable. I am not using body-parser, I am using express's inbuilt json and urlencoding methods.

Here is the formidable part.

```
const form = formidable({multiples: true});
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(`error is ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    console.log(`fields is ${JSON.stringify(fields)}`);
    console.log(`files JSON: ${JSON.stringify(files)}`);
    console.log('file in request: ' + files.payoutUpload);
    console.log(`req.body: ${req.body}`);
    options.file = files.payoutUpload;
});
```

I get err, fields and files as empty. I have searched through all similar questions and set the request headers correctly(which is usually the issue). I can see that the request.body still has the file payload on the server end. But formidable does not parse this. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have tried other packages for parsing the file, like multer, express-fileupload, all of them return files as empty. I have also tried fetch API to send my request, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
> ```

When you send `multipart/form-data` you **must** include a `boundary` parameter in the header however you **can't** know what value you need to set for this.

**Don't** set the `Content-Type` header at all. Allow `XMLHttpRequest` to generate it automatically from the `FormData` object.

Comment: I tried as you said. The xmlhttprequest object sets the content-type along with the correct boundary. However now the form.parse callback is not even called. Earlier I used to get empty files,fields and error. The request sends the file as FormData as shown in inspect network call in chrome.

Comment: the file seems to be sent in binary format. I have used this encoding in formidable as options to constructor. This has no effect though.

Comment: You are right about not setting the Content-Type header. The fetch-api or the xmlhttprequest object adds the required header along with the boundary. This is a case of formidable/multer not being able to parse the FormData. I added a text field to my form to see if it gets parsed, but even that is not getting parsed. So there is something else going on.